# I want to update my room DB field and also disable swipe in recyclerview item at the same time in Android how to achieve this?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, swipe

I have a recyclerview where when I swipe left I open a bottom sheet and select one value and then I need to update my room DB table and also disable swipe.
But currently im not able to do both things at the same time, only the disable swipe is working not able to update recyclerview item

```
swipeController = SwipeController(object:SwipeControllerActions() {
                override fun onRightClicked(position:Int) {
                    val bottomSheetFragment = BottomModalFragment()
                    bottomSheetFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, bottomSheetFragment.tag)
                    var homeTaskModel: HomeTaskModel = homeAdapter.getWordAtPosition(position)!!

                    TASK_STATUS.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                        homeTaskModel.task_status = it //passing value 
                        homeViewModel.updateSwipeType(1,0) //disable swipe
                        homeAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

                    })
                }
```

Below is my onbindviewholder code

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val tasks = taskslist[position]
        var task__status = tasks.task_status


        holder.Taskbinding.taskdata = taskslist[position]
        holder.Taskbinding.txtTaskname.text = tasks.taskname
        holder.Taskbinding.txtTaskStatus.text = task__status


        //hide unhide navigation imageview
        if (task__status.equals("Travel To Site"))
            holder.Taskbinding.imgNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else
            holder.Taskbinding.imgNavigation.visibility = View.GONE
      
    }
```

getItemViewType() is called before onBindViewHolder where I am updating my views

```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return taskslist.get(position).swipe_type
    }
```

How to acheieve both the scenarios???

Comment: post your adapter code and mainactivity where you updating your recyclerview

Comment: done. please check

Answer (score 0):

create refreshList in adapter class the refresh the list

```
fun refreshList(list:arrayOf()){
tasklist = list
}
```

call this function from mainActivity where you want to notify the adapter

```
homeAdapter.refreshList(pass your updated list here)
```

thats it!!